# Placeholder for Decimal Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

I am new to SQL so this question is likely simple and easy to answer.

I am creating a temp table in which I want a blank column to be filled later with decimal values.

Can I use as a placeholder in my SELECT statement to indicate that I want decimal values to fill the column?

For columns that I will fill with integer values, I am using the following code:

```
SELECT 0 AS ColumnName
```

I do not believe this will work for the column that I want filled with decimal values, as I believe the 0 indicates integer values instead. Is there something that I can use instead of the 0?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What DBMS (MySQL, Oracle, etc...) are you using?

Comment: `select 0.0 as decimal_column`

Comment: `SELECT CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,9)) as decimal_column` or `SELECT 0.0 AS decimal_column`

Comment: I am using Microsoft SSMS @Error_2646

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1bd8a/12

Comment: Did you use a CREATE statement before the SELECT or are you doing both in a single statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL will perform [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) of some types when it knows there is no risk of data loss. In your case, int can safely convert to decimal, because there's no way to corrupt your data. 0 is 0.0 as far as SQL is concerned.

The opposite would not be true, as casting from decimal to int would lose the decimal part. Therefore SQL would not implicitly cast the opposite.

Your query is good as is.

Answer (score 0):

Using a 0 in a float field will not cause truncation on the record since it contains less precision than a float, so it is safe to do this and implies a 0.0

You could also DEFAULT the field to 0.0 in the table declaration so it will be 0.0 until updated. But not required.

Ex: `CREATE TABLE table
    ( col1 FLOAT(size,d) DEFAULT 0.0 )`